# mysql can't insert in a table with 8 columns

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to insert datas in a table of 8 columns but it's doesn't work . i'm using mysql version 5.7.11 . however it works when i reduce it to 6 columns  7 columns refuse to work as well .

please find the tables and their php code below

1. 6 columns mysql/php

1.1 php

```
$res=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$table.'(title,description,image,city,price) VALUES(:titl,:decri,:img,:cty,:prce)');

$res->bindParam(':titl',$title);
     $res->bindParam(':decri',$decri);
     $res->bindParam(':img',$item_img);
     $res->bindParam(':cty',$city);
     $res->bindParam(':prce',$price);
```

1.2 mysql

```
 CREATE TABLE `mobiles` 
 (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`image` longblob NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2. 8 columns tables

2.1 mysql code

```
  CREATE TABLE `mobiles` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT   NULL,
 `image` longblob NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`price` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2.2 php code

```
$res=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO'.$table.'(title,description,image,city,price,user_id,date)    VALUES(:titl,:decri,:img,:cty,:prce,:user_id,:dte)');
     $res->bindParam(':titl',$title);
     $res->bindParam(':decri',$decri);
     $res->bindParam(':img',$item_img);
     $res->bindParam(':cty',$city);
     $res->bindParam(':prce',$price);
     $res->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id);
     $res->bindParam(':dte',$date);
```

i have executed right after , the six columns works but the 8 columns one

why is that more than 6 columns mysql can't insert while the number limit of columns can reach 255.

is there any issue in my code ? i echoed all the entries and they all work fine.

any help please ?

Comment: What is the error you're getting while inserting data? Have you tried to catch `PDOException` ?

Comment: You can see error message like this: `echo $res->errorInfo()[2];` after `$success =  $res->execute();` if `$success` is false;

Comment: there is no connection failure. yes i tried to catch PDO exception . it works fine when it's 6 columns but no row affected when i add two more fields .

Comment: try using \`date\`  enclosed in backtics ..

Comment: Have you tried moving user_id and date higher (at position 3 and 4) and check how many columns are affected. And are you sure that date and user_id isset and not null when binding?

Comment: yes they are set , i could insert user_id now . user_id is of type INT but i had set it to null so the error message was that i can't set user_id to null,

Comment: check for errors and come back to tell us what it was, and you do have one. Your `id` column is set to NOT NULL and that alone should be throwing you an error about it but you're probably not checking for errors.

Comment: we also have no idea where your data is being pulled from.

Comment: this question seems to have gone stale; I'm out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no space between `'INSERT INTO'` and `$table` in second query, so query fails because of syntax error.

Comment: It works actually with no space , the error is now the date format . date is of type DATETIME , and i have set date by '$date=date(Y-M-D);' , i'm guessing the error is there . thanks !!!

Comment: @JeanOuédraogo You have way too many unknowns in your questions. Now you start telling the person here what that `$date` variable is. Do you not know what `date(Y-M-D)` does? It's an outright syntax error and the format is wrong. You have other errors also but you failed to tell us what they were.

Comment: I have set date to NULL since it's taking the CURRENT TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Fred-ii- it actually works the errors were as follow:

Comment: @JeanOuédraogo You wrote in a comment above here using this code `$date=date(Y-M-D);` that is impossible if you say that works. All that will do is output `0`, that's **IF** that is your real code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it actually works the errors were as follow: my the  field user_id can't be set to null but i had actually set to null in my php code i have gone back to set it "null=yes" in my mysql table  the second error was my date the error thrown was "Datetime incorrect datetime value"  i did the same as user_id by setting date to null=yes in my mysql table. i did it as follow : `$date=NULL` `$user_id=NULL` `$res->bindParam(':user_id',$user_id,PDO::PARAM_NULL);``$res->bindParam(':dte',$date,PDO::PARAM_NULL);`

Comment: @JeanOuédraogo Look at the `date()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and the letters related to what you're passing in it: `Y` - `M` and `D`. You will quickly see that those do not match the format that MySQL needs here. However, had you quoted it like this `date('Y-M-D')` it would come out as `2016-Jul-Sat` being a valid date, just not for MySQL ;-) The (MySQL) DATETIME format https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html is `YYYY-MM-DD` and you may have thought that PHP's `date()` uses the same; it doesn't.

Comment: @JeanOuédraogo Then your `mobiles` table's `id` column is `int(11) NOT NULL` yet you didn't include it in your query; that alone should also be throwing an error about it. So, where are we with the question now? You still having problems?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i have set id to NULL=yes as well so that i  would't need to include it in the query . yes problem is solved . briefly i have set the fields not needed in the query to NULL=yes and i removed them from query . no no error thrown